# How define vendor chunk in Angular CLI build?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Any way to customize vendor chunk in Angular 4? I want to define certain areas of an application that uses certain 3rd party components that I don't want to load by default, basically I want to have the possibility to create multiple vendor chunks and load them according to the area of the application is being load, also I want to specify what to put in the default vendor chunk. I don't see options to achieve this by angular-cli?

Comment: Separate chunk means a separate js file when angular-cli compiled your stuff? If so, you might find your answer [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)

Comment: The only option that refers to vendor chunk is: --vendor-chunk and is "true" or "false"; so angular cli will create the vendor chunk based on imports from external modules, I can't find an option to selectively create chunks for certain vendor modules.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to consider doing an `ng eject`, and then tweak the build process as needed. More info on: [`ng eject`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject).